# Disable TreeNode Selection while dragging

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree, mouselistener

I have a Jtree and a custom MouseListener/MouseMotionListener who handles Scrolling on Touch Devices.

My Problem is now that when I start Dragging, the current Node will get instant selected when I'm pressing the mouse.

**Question:**
How can I disable the automatic selection when I drag the mouse (it should be selected when I click on it without dragging).

The `clicked` and `pressed` functions are empty in my DragscrollListener.

**Note:**

I haven't coded the DragScrollListener - it can be found [here](http://www.algosome.com/articles/java-swing-iphone-drag-component.html)

Sample Code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;

public class Test extends JFrame{

    public Test(){

        JTree tree = new JTree();

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        DragScrollListener ds = new DragScrollListener(tree);
        tree.addMouseListener(ds);
        tree.addMouseMotionListener(ds);

        getContentPane().add(pane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(100,100);

    }

    public static void main(String[]arghs){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). The first thing the above code would need to make it an MCVE is the code for the `DragScrollListener`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the needed behavior when drag is finished, override mouse released in
DragScrollListener by extending it. See comments for clarification:

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

    public Test(){

        JTree tree = new JTree();

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tree);

        //To control the needed behavior when drag is finished, override 
        //mouse released in DragScrollListener by extending it
        MyDragScrollListener ds = new MyDragScrollListener(tree);

        tree.addMouseListener(ds);
        tree.addMouseMotionListener(ds);

        getContentPane().add(pane);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(100,100);
    }

    //Subclass DragScrollListener to override mouse released 
    public class MyDragScrollListener extends DragScrollListener{

        public MyDragScrollListener(Component c) {
            super(c);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

            //add needed functionality when mouse is released 
            if( e.getSource() instanceof JTree) {

                System.out.println("source is a JTree");
                JTree tree = (JTree)e.getSource();

                //clear seelction
                 tree.clearSelection(); 

            }

            super.mouseReleased(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]arghs){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask if the code is not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it works fine for me

for the behaviour i wanted (selection on Click) i just had to add the click Methode and manually safe the selectionPath before i clear the selection and set it their again as the selection path.

Comment: I am glad it helped (0: . Up voted the question: I think it is well laid out and asked.